# Spring security redirect to login and restore form data previously entered

Tags: spring, redirect, authentication, spring-security, restore

**Overview**

1. I have Spring Web-Application secured with Spring Security
2. On the site there is a form to input some data, this form is public, but the data will only be processed for authenticated users
3. If the user press the submit button and is not yet logged in, he will be delegated to the login page. Was the login successfull the user will be redirected to a site where the result of the data processing is visible

**Problem**

In standard configuration all the data which has been setup by the user are lost after the login process. As I understand it its because a new HttpRequest is created for the redirect after the login.

**Solution**

1. I have to write a custom LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint which stores the form data in the session
2. I have to write a custom SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler which reads the date from the session an add them as parameters to the url

**WebApp Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityProperties security;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("user")
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/inputForm")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandlerCustom())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPointCustom("/login"));
    }
}
```

**Custom SuccessHandler**

```
public class SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandlerCustom extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String text = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("text");
        if (text != null) {
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("text");
            setDefaultTargetUrl("/user/dashboard/?text=" + text);
        }

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

**Custom EntryPoint**

```
public class LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPointCustom extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPointCustom(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
                    throws IOException,
                    ServletException {

        String text = request.getParameter("text");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("text", text);

        super.commence(request, response, authException);
    }
}
```

What would you say, is this a valid way to restore the form data, are the better/other solutions, maybe a standard way in spring?

**Update**

It seem's that something is still wrong with my configuration, cause as seen in the debug message, the request ist not saved by the "HttpSessionRequestCache". If I get this working I don't have to work around with custom implementations.

`o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /user/dashboard' doesn't match 'GET /**
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match`

Comment: The whole point of the saved request aware wrapper is that the previous request (or the request that lead to the login) is saved and restored after the login. If that isn't working you have something wrong in your setup.

Comment: thats what i expected too, but it seems that somthing with the matcher in org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) doesn't work. the matcher just contains "requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**'" and not what i've configured ... the debug message also say's "Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]" -> "Request 'POST /user/dashboard' doesn't match 'GET /**" -> "Did not match" -> "Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match"

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/HttpSessionRequestCache.java
You could implement your own RequestMatcher to solve this too. Might be related to the csrf filter?

Comment: kindly make sure that the form method is post like this <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post"></form>

Answer (score 0):

kindly make sure that the form method is post
like this

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post"> 
         <!-- form input -- >
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, but this solution is not related to the problem at all, i think you even didn't unterstand the problem ... but anyway, it's 5 years ago and it was a problem in my setup, as M. Deinum said, the saved request aware wrapper is responsible to do exactly what i wanted